# Rails scope for all posts except those that have inactive authors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I'm using Rails 3.2.19

Given

Posts have_one Author

and an Author has a boolean attribute Active

I need to write a scope that gives all posts except those that have inactive authors.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :author

  scope :all_except_inactive_authors

end
```

Comment: Why can't you add that condition in the scope itself?

Comment: I don't know how to write the condition

Comment: following construction;

'author.posts.where(and here is condition e.x. :active==true)'

Comment: Sorry @EugeneTkachenko I don't think that would work

Comment: Did you try anything? Rails guide has nice [explanation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#scopes) of scopes.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried a few things. My problem is I want the posts whether or not they have an author but if they do have an author the author has to be active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `post_id` from authors and added `author_id` to posts

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  scope :all_except_inactive_authors, -> { includes(:author).where("author_id is NULL or authors.active = ?", true) }
end
```

now from `author_id` a post knows that it has an author or not

Comment: Same problem as @fengd this only gives the posts that have an author, it should include those that don't have an author also

Answer (score 0):

First, I think `Post` should belongs_to `Author`,

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  scope :all_except_inactive_authors, -> { join(:author).where("authors.status = ?", :active) }
end
```

Comment: This only gives the posts that have an author, it should include those that don't have an author